# How to do equality check of two DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below scenario:

I have 2 dataframes containing only 1 column
Lets say

```
DF1=(1,2,3,4,5)
DF2=(3,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Basically those values are keys and I am creating a parquet file of DF1 if the keys in DF1 are not in DF2 (In current example it should return false). My current way of achieving my requirement is:

```
val df1count= DF1.count
val df2count=DF2.count
val diffDF=DF2.except(DF1)
val diffCount=diffDF.count
if(diffCount==(df2count-df1count)) true
else false
```

The problem with this approach is I am calling action elements 4 times which is for sure not the best way. Can someone suggest me the best effective way of achieving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `intersect` to get the values common to both DataFrames, and then check if it's empty:

```
DF1.intersect(DF2).take(1).isEmpty
```

That will use only one action (`take(1)`) and a fairly quick one.

Comment: The dataframes may have no common values but to be not equal.Jacek asked about equality check.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the check if Dataset first ist equal to Dataset second:

```
if(first.except(second).union(second.except(first)).count() == 0)
   first  == second
else
   first != second
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an intersection combined with a count this would assure the the contents are the same and the number of values in both are the same and asserts to a true

```
val intersectcount= DF1.intersect(DF2).count()

val check =(intersectcount == DF1.count()) && (intersectcount==DF2.count())
```